# How does ufw handle conflicting rules?

Tags: firewall, ufw

I recently had the following conflicting rules on ufw

```
445/tcp      ALLOW      192.168.1.0/24
445          DENY       anywhere
445          DENY       anywhere IPV6
```

because I first blocked the 445 to then allow it only on my subnet. I was doing that as part of the samba configuration on my local network and I noticed that such conflicting rules did not impact some of my devices (2 pcs and a playstation connecting to the samba server) but impacted an android phone connecting to the server.

I could do some tests here to try to infer how does ufw handle those "conflicting rules", however I though I would probably get a more accurate answer here =D

Does ufw overwrite the ALLOWS on top of the DENYs? Or how does it handle those type of conflicts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ufw` does not "handle the conflicts" in any way, it just puts the rules into an `iptables chain` which follows the **first-match** policy.

So if a packet matches a rule which drops it, it will be dropped regardless of any other matching rules which may follow.

Comment: does that mean that the drop rule overwrite the allow rule? Or it is really by the order in which the rule has been added, so if I first add an allow and then a deny, it will allow?

Comment: a) It doesn't "overwrite" it, it is just executed and no other rules are examined. b) yes. BTW: in `ufw` you can use the **insert** keyword to insert rules anywhere in the ruleset.