# ufw not blocking traffic

Tags: networking, server, firewall, ufw

I have an apache2.4 webserver, and I am trying to block a malicious subnet using ufw.
 Here is the UFW setup:

```
$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
Anywhere                   DENY IN     X.X.X.0/24
```

I to test, I added a rule to block my own IP but I can still view the pages, and site, so evidently, UFW is not blocking traffic from my IP. I can only assume the case is the same for the blocked subnet.

Please, how can I block subnets from accessing my webpages?

Comment: It will help you too: http://askubuntu.com/questions/323544/how-does-ufw-handle-conflicting-rules

Answer (score 3):

(If you're running  apache server at port 80). UFW parses the **rule in sequential manner**, so when the rule matches i.e you allow anyone from anywhere to access your 80 port, as the match is found, you're packet is accepted. **It follows the first-match policy**.

So now try again and configure it, if problem persist, write a comment below . !